# How to evenly distribute elements in array such that their distance is maximized?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

How to evenly distribute elements in array such that their distance is maximized? If

```
a=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

Which is the best algorithm to generate evenly distributed array a, such that:

```
a=[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
```

Comment: could you clearify what distance you mean? It seems like you want to spread out each of the  groups (1, 2, and 3) such that minimal distance between the array positions in the groups is maximal across all groups, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. How to go about it?

Comment: hmm, currently im struggling with edge cases: However, the basic idea is as follows:  First start with the largest group and spread it out evenly: then got to the second largest group and spread it evenly in the remaining "zeros" and so on. Thus, the largest group should determine the maximal minimal distance between groups

Comment: This strategy won't work for all the cases.
Consider input:
    a=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3]
As per your solution, the answer would be:
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,1], but the ideal answer should be [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2] because of maximized distances.

Comment: Of course you are right. However, what you could do here is: if there is more than one largest group: zip those groups (ie consider pairs (1,2)) and fill the array with pairs. The perform the recurse downwards. However, this iwll only help for this case. Probably this can be solved using combinatorical optimization, but I almost know nothing about that topic, sorry ;)